# MySQL : Trigger Syntax not correct

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm trying to write a trigger for a table named `classes_tbl` where I basically want to check `before update` if the participants are at the maximum, if true - do not allow update, and raise error message.
As well as check if participants = 0 in case the the `update table` tries to decrease the number, it needs not to be possible to decrease below 0 - and again raise an error message in this case.

I'm not 100% accustomed to MySQL so I'm not sure what is missing or wrong. It would be nice If someone could give me a hint.

Here is my Create Trigger syntax:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER MaxBelegt_TRGGR
BEFORE UPDATE ON classes_tbl
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN
DECLARE 
n_count NUMBER(3);
msg varchar(255);

SELECT maxParticipants
INTO n_count
FROM rooms_tbl
WHERE rid = :NEW.rid;

IF :OLD.participants = n_count THEN
set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: MaxParticipants for Room exceeded. On MaxBelegt_TRGGR -> belegtAnz : ', cast(OLD.participants as char));
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg; 
END IF;

IF :NEW.participants < 0 THEN
set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Participant number already 0. On MaxBelegt_TRGGR -> belegtAnz : ', cast(OLD.participants as char));
        signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg; 
END IF; 
END
//
DELIMITER;
```

Thank You!

BTW: I'm using mysql version : 5.6.24 .. just in case

Comment: You're missing the space between `DELIMITER` and `;`. If that doesn't fix it, could you show us your table definition and the exact text of the error message?

Comment: @DarwinvonCorax I just fixed it ! I had to get rid of the `:` in front of the `NEW` and `OLD` variables as well as add `DECLARE` for both variables created -> `DECLARE n_count integer; DECLARE msg varchar(255);`

After that the Trigger worked. But when it reached the maxParticipant number it didn't want to decrease it anymore, so I also had to change `IF NEW.participants > n_count THEN`. 

Now everything is fine. Thanks!